# parsing GLTF buffer with Qt

Tags: c++, json, qt, gltf

Here's the situation.

Let's say I have a gltf file containing :

```
"uri" : "data:application/gltf-buffer;base64,AAAIAAcAAAABAAgAAQAJAAgAAQACAAkAAgAKAAkAAgADAAoAAwALAAoAAwAEAAsABAAMAAsABAAFAAwABQANAAwABQAGAA0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAPwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAABAQAAAAAAAAAAAAACAQAAAAAAAAAAAAACgQAAAAAAAAAAAAADAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgD8AAAAAAACAPwAAgD8AAAAAAAAAQAAAgD8AAAAAAABAQAAAgD8AAAAAAACAQAAAgD8AAAAAAACgQAAAgD8AAAAAAADAQAAAgD8AAAAACAAKAAwAAAAAAIA/AAAAQAAAAAAAAEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAKBAAACAQAAAAAA=",
```

I understand how to extract the type and the base using `QJsonValue::toString()` and `QString` parsing functions (like `split(";")`)  but my problems remain : I have now a string that correspond to my gltf buffer and I don't know how to read it. (I know what it is, an d how the data should be interpreted thanks to *accessors* and *bufferviews*)

**tldr:** how to convert that string of letters to a `QByteArray` ?

Comment: This is a base64 data URI, most programming languages have methods to parse these strings to binary data. You may need to add tags to the question for the languages and code involved here.

Comment: I've added C++ as tag. I'm specifically trying to find a C++/Qt-based method for this, but I couldn't find anything for the last 4 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you tried it like that?))

```
QByteArray by = QByteArray::fromBase64("AAAIAAcAAAABAAgAAQAJAAgAAQACAAkAAgAKAAkAAgADAAoAAwALAAoAAwAEAAsABAAMAAsABAAFAAwABQANAAwABQAGAA0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAPwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAABAQAAAAAAAAAAAAACAQAAAAAAAAAAAAACgQAAAAAAAAAAAAADAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgD8AAAAAAACAPwAAgD8AAAAAAAAAQAAAgD8AAAAAAABAQAAAgD8AAAAAAACAQAAAgD8AAAAAAACgQAAAgD8AAAAAAADAQAAAgD8AAAAACAAKAAwAAAAAAIA/AAAAQAAAAAAAAEBAAABAQAAAAAAAAKBAAACAQAAAAAA=");
```

Comment: That worked indeed. I don't know how I could miss that (I guess I was too much looking at QUrl and QString to think it would be a QByteArray static). Thank you !